# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have gone through many examples and tried up to this but not getting success and it shows the error like this. What should be the correct way to solve this error ?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>IX-ONE Sample Application</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mycontainer"></div>


        <script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() { 

         $.ajax({  
                url:'https://exchange.ix-one.net/',  
                type:'post',  // or put
                contentType: 'application/json', // type of data
                Authorization:'TokenString',
                            data: '{“EntityName” : “Product”,“PropertyName” : “Allergens”}', // make JSON string
                    async: true,
                    dataType: 'jsonp', //you may use jsonp for cross origin request
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        $('#mycontainer').val(data);
                    }
                });

            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
 

<!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: @Satpal It was by default generated by Netbeans. But after removing that also getting same error.

Comment: Which type of file you are using `JSP`?

Comment: @Satpal Yes it is JSP page.

Comment: <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> remove from top line it may helpful for you

Comment: Can you check your `src` pointers of the scripts you are including if they are pointing to correct files? You may also want to check the `Content-Type` returned. The "<" problem may mean that instead of JSON or javaScript, you are getting HTML. Using tools like Firebug might help you to check you server response.

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

This also didn't worked

Comment: Not related to your problem, but if the auth token you show in the question is valid, then you need revoke that one immediately.

Comment: What is the expected output? I think you are getting an html page while the expected output is data wrapped in a callback function.

Comment: If i remove jsonp than it will be a Cross-Origin Error.

Comment: Instead of contentType: 'SampleToken'. Try with `Authorization: Bearer TOKEN`

Comment: @Taleeb already used that. SampleToken is for reference purpose. It was misplaced while editing the code.